# [Visual Studio Code]: Run task on save

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, build, vscode-tasks

I want do develop C programs with vscode.

My `tasks.json`, which describes the build stage if I understood that correctly, looks like this:

```js
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "default"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Since all the compiler errors are generated by the build, I would like to run it every time I save the file. This allows me to get immediate compiler feedback.

How can I set this up this? Note that most Plugins like [Run on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) don't work, since I can't specify the task, just the command, and then I won't get the compiler errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Trigger Task on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.triggertaskonsave) extension.

To set it up, add the following to your `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
"triggerTaskOnSave.tasks": {
  "C/C++: gcc build active file": [
    "*", // <-- Glob pattern to specify which files should trigger the task
  ],
}
```

Comment: I actually don't use VS code anymore, so I'm just gonna accept this answer without testing :S. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @TobTobXX You are welcome and thanks for trusting me :) I saw that this was an old question, but I was looking for the same. When I found the solution, I answered this so you, but also others who find this question on Google can find a solution.